# Reverse hangman #11

Tags: word, letters

If you put in an "s", you might be offending me.

If you put in an "f", it's faster than riding the subway.

If you put in a " b", the rainbow colors are disappearing.

The answer should be in the form

> _pple

followed by an explanation.

Comment: The missing letter must be the first one, like in the example? Or it could be in any position?

Comment: It could potentially be in any position

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My guess is

> _light

If you put in an "s", you might be offending me.

> A 'slight' is an insult

If you put in an "f", it's faster than riding the subway.

> 'Flight' is certainly faster than the subway (this could also be a play on words in that flight is the 'super' way as opposed to the 'sub' way.)

If you put in a " b", the rainbow colors are disappearing.

> 'Blight' is the browning of plant tissue infected by a pathogenic organism.

Comment: oh for god's sake

Comment: beat you by a second

Comment: @Zabari ...by which you mean 1 minute and 16 seconds.

Answer (score 8):

Possibly

> _ l i g h t
>
>  A **slight** is an insult
>  A **flight** is faster than taking the subway
>  A **blight** is a plant disease that saps them of their color

Answer (score 4):

i will just go ahead and give it a chance:

> _illy

If you put in an "s", I'd be offended.

> silly obviously offending

If you put in an "f", it's faster than the subway.

> filly: a young female horse, especially one less than four years old.

If you put in a " b", the rainbow is disappearing.

> billy: not sure about it but there is a billy the gnome and it is related about rainbow

Comment: Good guess, but I was thinking in a different direction.